# How to keep header of the file when using grep?

Tags: grep

I have two files. One very large file with a header and approx several million rows (chrall.txt.gz).

Another file (extract0.3.txt) with a single column/list of values to cross-reference the larger file. If the value match (they all should) a new file is created outputting the matched lines. I am using the  grep command below:

```
gunzip -c chrall.txt.gz | grep -Fwf extract0.3.txt > output
```

However, this does not print my header line. How would I retain the header line of chrall.txt.gz

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use grep specifically? It seems like awk (or sed) would be a better fit for the requirement.

Comment: Grep is the first thing that came to my head. I am new to awk too but prefer grep since I've used this before